# Which jboss.home does embeddable EJBContainer want?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have preinstalled `Jboss Eap 6.1.1`
When I run following line:

```
EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
```

I get exception: `javax.ejb.EJBException: Neither JBOSS_HOME nor jboss.home is set`

When I add:

```
System.setProperty("jboss.home", "/usr/local/share/jboss-eap-6.1/");
```

I face exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: Can't find directory /usr/local/share/jboss-eap-6.1/lib
```

---

**Edited:**

`JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider.createEJBContainer()` contains such code:

```
addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/lib");
addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/common/lib");
addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/server/" + serverConfig + "/lib")
addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/client");
```

I don't have such directories in my `Jboss Eap 6.1.1`. 
Which `jboss.home` does `EJBContainer` need?

Comment: The exception seems to come from [JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider.java](https://github.com/jbossejb3/jboss-ejb3-embedded/blob/master/standalone/src/main/java/org/jboss/ejb3/embedded/impl/standalone/JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider.java). Which libraries are in the class path when you run your code? Maybe this post could help [getting-started-with-embeddable-jboss-eap-6-as-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032303/getting-started-with-embeddable-jboss-eap-6-as-7)

Comment: @SubOptimal,  you are right. The exception comes from:`JBossStandaloneEJBContainerProvider` And there is lines in this class: `addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/lib");
      addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/common/lib");
      addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/server/" + serverConfig + "/lib");
      addClassPath(cp, jbossHome + "/client");` I don't have this directories in my `Jboss Eap 6.1.1`